# Load video from local server via filepath and, not via URL

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I'm writing a Flash-based video player which simply plays FLV videos. A filename is passed in via a `flashvar`.

Presently, this is achieved with the following function:

```
function loadVideo():void {
    var myVideo:FLVPlayback = new FLVPlayback();
    myVideo.align = VideoAlign.CENTER;
    myVideo.autoPlay = false;
    myVideo.skin = root.loaderInfo.parameters.skin;
    myVideo.skinAutoHide = true;
    myVideo.skinBackgroundColor = 0x00749E;
    myVideo.source = videosDirectory + root.loaderInfo.parameters.filename;
    myVideo.width  = stage.stageWidth;   // make scalable!
    myVideo.height = stage.stageHeight;  // make scalable!
    myVideo.x = myVideo.y = 0;
    stage.addChild(myVideo);
}
```

A video is grabbed and then added to the stage, with a player skin overlaid.

However, what I want to do is load a video from the file system (the same server the SWF is deployed to) rather than fetching a video from a URL. Reading the documentation for the `source` property tells me it will only accept URLs.

The reason I want to read from the file system is because these videos will be stored outside the root of the server. For example, a standard Apache set-up:

```
public_ftp/ 
public_html/ 
    assets/ 
        swf/ 
videos/
```

The SWF will be deployed to `/assets/swf/` but I then want to fetch videos from the `/videos/` directory.

Is this possible? Will I have to use an alternative solution other than Flash's `FLVPlayback` component? I'm by no standards an experienced Flash/ActionScript developer so simple, idiot-proof answers would be good.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible unless you have an HTTP or RTMP access to one of these files.

The swf is downloaded by the client, every request made from the swf must be available from the client. Just ask yourself the question "Would a browser be allowed to access this file?".

Comment: That's the thing: I don't want the browser to have access to the file. I don't want someone to be able to download the raw `.flv` files, rather only have them available to be viewed through this SWF video player. Think of it like YouTube's video player.

Comment: Then you may give your swf an unique id through FlashVars and allow only one download of the video per id server-side. It's not perfect but nothing is when dealing with Flash and security, the only point is to make people give up trying.

Comment: Thanks, Kodiak. Like I say I'm not a seasoned Flash developer, could you show me a simple implementation of using the unique ID approach you suggested please?

Comment: Actually, the complex part of it is on the server. Basically, the FlashVars (in the html) gives `key=384132343` (where the key is an unique random number put in your database). In the Flash you will have to ask for `.../index.php?video=12&key=384132343`. The server will serve the video 12 and then put the seen flag in the database to true for this key. I'm not an expert at this, there may be smarter solutions.

Comment: No, Kodiak, that's fine, thanks. It's enough food for thought for me. Was just having trouble getting my head around the original concept. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You could get the URL directory of the SWF, and then append the file name to create an absolute path.

Example:

```
function getDirectory():String {    
    var url:String = this.loaderInfo.url;
    var urlPieces:Array = url.split("/");
    urlPieces.pop();
    urlPieces.push("");
    var directory:String = urlPieces.join("/");
    return directory;
}
```